# Change the model that modelForm's save, is saving

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

Suppose i have a modelForm of a parent class MyUser, which holds the common information of users.

Users have a field, named role that indicates what role are they in, and i have 3 special models, for 3 of the roles.

What i want to do is to check the role field of my form, when saving the form.If it's one of those 3 special roles, I want to save the special Model (which is a child of MyUser) instead of MyUser, otherwise, i want the save method to perform normally.(save the actual MyAbstractUser).

```
class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    retyped_pass = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput, max_length=30, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser

    def save(self, ?):
        if self.fields['role'] == 'researcher'
             save ResearcherUser instead of MyUser
        ....
        else: # if none of above
             save MyUser
```

Special user types are ResearcherUser, ProducerUser and CenterUser, and if the role is none of these 3, i want it to be a MyUser.

Any idea how can i achieve this ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that fields in the model form for `MyUser` are exactly similar to fields of your special user types, you can do something like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.fields['role'] == 'researcher'
             return ResearchUser.objects.get_or_create( **self.fields)
        ....
        else: # if none of above
             super(MyUserForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note: you may want to use something better than `.get_or_create()`, which will do look up for existing objects on all fields provided. But it may not find one and try to create new.

Refer [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for exact behavior.